# How do I fix an AssertionError when using pygooglevoice to login

Tags: python, google-voice

I have scoured the internet for fixes but have found a few that were an issue in 2016 but none of them worked. Here's the line of code that throws an error:

```
voice.login('*************@gmail.com', '***********')
```

The Asterisk are the characters of my email and password.

Here's the error message it gave me:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\googlevoice\voice.py", line 99, in login
>   assert self.special
> AssertionError
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\harpe\Desktop\Ministry Manager Excel Based\Ministry_Manager.py", line 18, in <module>
>   voice.login('*************@gmail.com', '***********')
>   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\googlevoice\voice.py", line 101, in login
>   raise util.LoginError
> googlevoice.util.LoginError
> ```